# Select vs Select new in linq

Tags: linq

What's the difference b/w select and select new in linq.

```
var SelectNew = from L1 in liStudent select new { L1.Name, L1.ID };

var SelectNew2 = from L2 in liStudent select L2;
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first one, `SelectNew` is returning an enumerable of anonymous types with two properties, `Name` and `ID`, whereas `SelectNew2` is returning an enumerable of `iiStudent` entities.  You'd use the first instance when you need to return a subset of the data available in the entity/model.