# LINQ: Difference between "select new {e.FName, e.LName}" and "select (e.FName, e.LName)"?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

What is the difference between those two queries?

```
var query = from e in people
                select (e.FName,e.LName);
```

and

```
var query = from e in people
                select new {e.FName,e.LName};
```

Comment: Run each query and hover your mouse cursor over the `query` variable.  Visual Studio will tell you what the types returned from each query are.

Comment: The first selects a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) and the second selects an [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).

Comment: `(a, b)` is a *tuple*, when `new {a, b}` is an *anonymous object*

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: What happens before .NET 4.7?  The documentation states that `ValueTuple` was introduced in .NET 4.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select vs Select new in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529865/select-vs-select-new-in-linq)

Comment: @RobertHarvey And tuples only gained C# language support at v7.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Gotcha.

Comment: @tpc: you can put as many `7` properties into a [value] tuple: `(a), (a, b), (a, b, c), ..., (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)` or use `7 + rest` value tuple

Answer (score 3):

The first returns an `IEnumerable<ValueTuple<string, string>>` (see [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0)) where the second return an `IEnumerable<>` of an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).